# InnoDB + innodb_file_per_table: Configurable extent size to avoid wasted disk space?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

I've been experimenting with MariaDB (Win32 / 5.5.34-MariaDB-31.1), trying to use it as a DB server for a real-time archive application. I use `innodb_file_per_table=1`, so every table is a separate `.ibd` file. That's convenient for maintenance such as `OPTIMIZE TABLE` when old data will be deleted.

I have a small test application with some 2,600 tables (one table is used per an archived object). On the disk these tables consume some 12 GB, useful data (`data_length` + `index_length`) is about 4 GB (so far I've been only inserting/updating rows, no deletes). When adding `data_length` + `index_length` + `data_free`, I see 9 GB.

The major problem seems to be the way individual `.ibd` files grow. I've performed 2 tests (on both `COMPACT` and `COMPRESSED` tables). First they grow by few kB, but then their size jumps. E.g.: 163 kB, 180 kB, 229 kB ... 589 kB, 606 kB and then jump to 2 MB, then to 9 MB.

This observation agrees with [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_autoextend_increment) which says:

> This variable does not affect the per-table tablespace files that are
>   created if you use `innodb_file_per_table=1`. Those files are
>   auto-extending regardless of the value of `innodb_autoextend_increment`.
>   The initial extensions are by small amounts, after which extensions
>   occur in increments of 4 MB.

So it seems every table (grown above some limit) has 0-4 MB unused but allocated space (let's say 2 MB on average). I wasn't able to find anything in documentation which would suggest this extent size can be configured. And that's my question:

Can this auto-extension size be changed on MySQL/MariaDB/other alternative to MySQL? The current 2 MB per table is an unacceptably high overhead (production systems may have 100,000 tables or more, that is 200 GB wasted space).

When we use Oracle, it doesn't have a 'one_file_per_table' option, but to avoid fragmentation of datafiles (caused by deleting old data and then tidying up by `alter table shrink space`) the tablespace is created using `space EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL UNIFORM SIZE 128 K` which tells Oracle to use a fixed-size extent instead of default growing extent size.
(the default growing-extent caused situations when a fixed-size tablespace had over 10 GB of free space, but a table was not able to expand because there was not a sufficiently large contiguous block available. All 10 GB was reclaimed after deleting old data which was in small extents).

Comment: 2600 tables? One table per object? Maybe you should simply rethink your DB design.

Comment: Hello, yes, one table per object. I'll not go into greater details, but there are "simple archives" - e.g. imagine archiving a temperature measured by a sensor (this table has columns DATETIME, DOUBLE value and some INT flags). There are "structured archives" - e.g. imagine archiving a "worksheet" with 5 rows and 3 columns .. in each cell there is a different temperature (so this table will have also columns ROWNUM,COLNUM to tell which cell we're talking about) . And between these, it's also possible to archive "1 column of worksheet" (so there'll be only ROWNUM but not COLNUM).

Comment: Continuing: some applications have ten thousands of objects. Big archive databases (500+ GB) are on Oracle, small (10-30 GB) on Sybase Anywhere .. we're experimenting with PGSQL (cca 150k tables, 50 GB database), now I'd try to play with MySql/MariaDB. 
Putting multiple objects into single table is not a solution for us. Setting innodb_file_per_table=0 will probably cause constant growth of ibd file when we do OPTIMIZE TABLE after periodical deletion of data older than required history depth.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that could use some clarification. InnoDB tables are organized into 1 MB extents which with the default page size for uncompressed tables is 64 pages. Very small tables with `innodb_file_per_table = 1` are allowed to be less than one extent, mainly as an optimization for people who have many very small tables. However as the table grows beyond a few pages it starts to ramp up the allocation sizes in order to avoid overhead and minimize fragmentation of the table, as you noticed. Not a lot of thought has gone into improving this strategy for use cases like yours, primarily because your use case is a bit of a database anti-pattern.

So, the real answer is that you should reconsider your database design.

However, with your current database design, you may have better luck with `innodb_file_per_table = 0`. In that case all tables will end up in a single file called `ibdata1` (or a few files if you manually configure the tablespace size) and that will grow as necessary. If you delete data or rebuild tables with e.g. `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, the space made available inside `ibdata1` will be efficiently reused for other tables as needed. There isn't currently a way to shrink any tablespace file in InnoDB (`.ibd` or `ibdataX`) so you won't be able to get the disk space back to the operating system, unfortunately. However, you can get it "back" and it can be reused within InnoDB, so you shouldn't worry about it growing indefinitely.

Comment: Thank you for information!
If we locate all tables in an ibdata1 (and other manually created files), do tables grow also by a few pages and then by 1MB extents to avoid fragmentation? (that means on average 1/2 MB wasted space pre table instead of 2MB). So if old data is deleted from tables, it leaves behind a few pages which won't be reused unless there's a contiguous area of 64 of them available? And doing OPTIMIZE TABLE does the enginge start allocating 1MB extents for the new table if it knows (data_length + index_length) that the table is not small?

Comment: I liked the idea of one-table-per-file (as in PGSQL or MyISAM) - we can handle fragmentation also by periodically defragmenting the disk - which is something that won't be achieved when putting all tables into one file.
We have a PostgreSQL production server with a 50GB database having 150 000 tables, regular vacuuming and defragmentation on weekends .. uptime is 7 months without any problem or admin intervention.
One of customers runs our system for years using Oracle10g, 600GB + 500k tables..but new Ora11g has long-time stability issues resulting in ORA-04031.

Comment: Thinking through it, yes, even if you use the `innodb_file_per_table = 0` mode with all tables in `ibdata1`, once an individual file segment (there are two per index) within an index within a table exceeds 32 pages, whole extents (1 MB) will be allocated to it. I will update my answer a bit to include more of this information.  These may be some useful links for you: http://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/03/the-basics-of-innodb-space-file-layout/, http://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/04/page-management-in-innodb-space-files/, and the whole series http://blog.jcole.us/innodb/.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this technique as a compromise:

- Put the larger tables in file_per_table.
- Put the smaller tables in ibdata1.

As a rough guess, you could use the [*80-20 rule*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle) that says that probably 20% of the tables consume 80% of the space.  So those should be file_per_table.  But YMMV.  (And, take into consideration Jeremy's comments.)

If everything is currently in ibdata1, you have to dump, remove ibdata1, and reload.  A costly mess.

If everything is currently in .ibds:

- Set the global `innodb_file_per_table = ON`.
- Log out
- Log back in (to get the setting)
- Repeat: `ALTER TABLE tbl... ENGINE=InnoDB;` -- to copy from .ibd to ibdata1 and drop the .ibd.
- When finished, keep in mind that new tables will either go in ibdata1 or .ibd, depending on where you leave the setting.

Future releases may allow to assign tables to "tablespaces" instead of just the extremes of 1/table vs ibdata1.  That will open new optimization techniques.  I'm thinking: 1 tablespace per database, plus big tables still in their own .ibd.  Meanwhile, no tables in ibdata1.  (Of course, if your 2600 tables are in a single database, this does not help.)

Another note:  `PARTITIONed` tables are especially wasteful since they have "free" space in each partition.  "Native partitions" should improve on this.  (But I don't have any metrics yet.)